# MS Skype bot isn't responding

Tags: botframework, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I use Azure to create my bot. The Telegram, Web and S4B channels works as expected, but the Skype channel doesn't work. I don't get any error.

[image]

To create the Skype channel I just click the "Add channel" link and add the new contact to my Skype contacts. Is it enough?

[image]

[image]

Could you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of issue was the turned off ciphers the my IIS:
[image]

When I turn on all of these my skype bot start to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect Skype to your bot, all you need to do is click on the Skype option in the '**Add a featured channel**' and then configure the settings in  Web control, Messaging, Calling, Groups and Publish.

- In your case, click on the '**Messaging**' tab and make sure that the '**enable messaging**' option is selected. Once your changes are saved, you can add the bot to your contacts and it will work.
- Skype can take up to 15 minutes to propagate the settings changes. Wait for a few minutes before sending a message to the bot.
- If it still doesn't work, delete the channel and again following the steps above to add the Skype channel to your bot. You can also use **ngrok** to [debug any channel locally](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/).

Comment: Thank you, but I created my bot according to the instructions and waited more than day. It doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the messaging endpoint and save it and then change it back(to force propagation to skype connector service). Also, did you try debugging locally using ngrok?

Comment: Thank you, I changed the endpoint and changed it back couple days ago it didn't help me, I didn't debug it, but I use the IIS logs to see all incomming request, I see request from other channels but I doen's see from skype.

Comment: Can you post your bot's Microsoft App ID? I will forward it to the Skype Bot Support team. Are you having the same issue when you are trying to connect the Skype channel to another bot?

Comment: It started to work after I changed endpoint to my local machine using ngrok. Thank you for your support!

Comment: But if I change the endpoint back, I get the same issue, btw did you pick up my ms app id? I've already removed it for security reason.

Comment: I try to catch network packages by Wireshark and I see the packedges, but IIS doesn't get requests, only from skype channel, It works good from other channels. The strange issue.